# How to bind traffic of each NAT client to a external IP address?

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat

I have a NAT router with 2 IP addresses, lets say `111.111.111.111` and `222.222.222.222` associated with the interfaces `eth0` and `eth0:1` respectively.

I have two servers that connect to this NAT gateway through the interface `tap0` (OpenVPN clients), with the IPs `10.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.2`. I want them to impersonate each of the NAT router's IP addresses.

So far I made the following `iptables` rules:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -d 111.111.111.111/32 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.0.0.1
iptables -A PREROUTING -d 222.222.222.222/32 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.0.0.2
```

This is routing all incoming connections to the right server. Howover, outgoing connections are still using the same IP address to access the web. How can I create a rule that will force all outgoing traffic of those local servers to use it's respective external IP address and achieve the impersonation effect I want?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I ended up figuring it out myself, aparently my issue was that this rule must be added before the `-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` one.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/32 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 111.111.111.111
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.2/32 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 222.222.222.222
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```